# Reorganizing activities in different folders

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to change the structure of my android application to have the activites in a subfolder called activities. So, my code structure will become

`com.example.myapp.activities.MainActivity`

and all the activities will reside within **com.example.myapp.activities**

How do I achieve this ? Also, What changes will have to be made in the manifest for this to work ? How will I access other activity classes from within other activities ?

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

EDIT : I achieved this using dragging and dropping the activities in the folders but now I am getting this error on `setContentView(R.layout.main);` : **main cannot be resolved or is not a 
 field**

Comment: Please import your R file in this class.

Answer (score 1):

If you organize all activities in same packages, then you have to define the activity without package declaration in Manifest file, example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myapp.activities"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:name=".WorldClockApplication"

    <activity
        android:name=".WorldClockHomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
                  <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".AddLocationActivity"/>         
    <activity   android:name=".EditPreference"/>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Then you should call that activity inside another activity using intent. Consider I'm  calling WorldClockHomeActivity from WorldClockApplication activity as follows:

```
  Intent myIntent=new Intent(WorldClockApplication.this,WorldClockHomeActivity.class);
  startActivity(myIntent);
```

Then do clean, refresh your project you wont get error in your project. If get error on

```
 setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

that means you have problem in res/strings or res/layout or res/drawable folders not in manifest file

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Eclipse` create a new packet in your project and drag and drop your activities files in there. Eclipse will take care of all the necessary changes.

The changes are in your directory structure and in the manifest as you have posted in the question.

Activities can be launched (or new `Intents` can be sent to them) as usual through `Intent(context, YourActivity.class)`;

I wouldn't move the activities though, rather I'd organize **other** Java classes in separate packages.

Comment: EDIT : I achieved this using dragging and dropping the activities in the folders but now I am getting this error on `setContentView(R.layout.main);` : **main cannot be resolved or is not a 
 field**

Comment: Don't move any xml files they have to be in their directories. Do Clean Project and then Build Project (if it doesn't build automatically)